# WakefulBroadcastReceiver onReceive not triggering android GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast

I implemented `GCM` notifications in Android and everything was working fine. I'm sending Notifications to the phone via a PHP server using the Google Cloud Messaging Service.
After a week or so I installed that app again on my phone and send a test notification onto my phone but I got nothing. The PHP script runs without any error with `success=1` and no cononical id's in the GCM response.   `WakufulBroadcastReceiver` isn't triggered in the android app.

Here is the complete code that I am using:

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("", "In Receive Method of Broadcast Receiver");
        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, intent.setComponent(cn));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**GcmMessageHandler.java**

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService{

    Handler handler;
    public GcmMessageHandler() {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public GcmMessageHandler(String name) {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        final String message = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
         Log.d("GCM", "Received : (" +messageType+")  "+intent.getExtras().getString("name"));
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_push_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.test_push_app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test_push_app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.test_push_app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmMessageHandler" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In **MainActivity.java** I am using this task to register

```
private class Register extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        String regID;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                regID = gcm.register("40441*******");

            }catch(Exception ex){
                regID = "Failed";
                //Log.d("", ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return regID;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            etRegid.setText(result);
            Log.d("", result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

**PhpResponse:**

```
{
    "multicast_id": 7260653358308753695,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "0:1422710889970517%ef663a58f9fd7ecd"
    }]
}
```

Help me! Thanks.

Note: `GooglePlayServices` are installed in the phone as well. I get no error while registration.

Comment: pls post entire log cat.and also check php script response while sending gcm.

Comment: log cat has nothing to show. nothing related. and php script gives no response.

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani See the php response above

Comment: Have you tried on different devices? You may take look at [here](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/managing-an-android-device-s-awake-state.html) to gain some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

1. Signed the build with the correct key (dev vs production)
2. Updated your php script to send the message to the new GCM registration id

Comment: I am in debug mode. installing directly from eclipse into the phone.Then i am registering the app and using this regID in php script. script gives no error but app don't receive anything. my internet connection is working fine on the phone.