# Handle message with both data and notification payload from onMessageReceived

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I need to send message that contains both 'data' and 'notification' payload. The message will be sent to a topic which subscriber can be from iOS or Android device.

In Android, is there any way for message with both notification and data payload to be **always** received at onMessageReceived instead of at system tray and intent extras? This including when the app is on background.

I can't remove the notification payload (send only 'data' payload) because the notification payload needed for iOS subscriber

Comment: Basing from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#receive_and_handle_messages), receiving the message when in background is the behavior of Android itself. Not sure if you can alter that out. What I'm thinking of instead is, maybe there is a way to check the System Tray/extras intent then direct the flow to the same method that is in you `onMessageReceived()`. Just a thought tho.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if it helps, this is the (C#) objects I used to send notifications for both IOS and Android.

```
    internal class jsonObj
    {
        //public bool delay_while_idle { get; set; }
        public data data { get; set; }
        public notification notification { get; set; }
        public string to { get; set; }
        public string priority { get; set; }
    }

    internal class data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int commentId { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string licensePlateCode { get; set; }
        public int licensePlateId { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    internal class notification
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
        public string sound { get; set; }
        public string badge { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("content-available")]
        public string contentAvailable { get; set; }
    }
```

At the moment of writing that code I used the old `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and `IntentService` in android, which is not recommended anymore. But if interested, it looked like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251934/wakefulbroadcastreceiver-onreceive-not-triggering-android-gcm)

**EDIT:**
OP commented about [this post on github](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/63). The same issue is described there which is still not fixed (September 2016). Workarounds can be found there, you have to send different requests for IOS and Android.

Comment: I think I found the issue for this this problem.
It's because "The current implementation doesn't allow to send a message that is simultaneously a display notification for ios and a silent notification for android."
ref : https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/63

So I think the only possible solution for now is to send different payload between iOS and android.